# Theta and Alpha Symbols In QLabel

Tags: qt, unicode, input, symbols, qlabel

I'm a student programmer and I'm using Qt to create a Gui that gets input from users for a simulation. I am trying to use the theta and alpha symbol in a QLabel. I have looked over [Qt's QLabel Documentation](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qlabel.html) and found that QLabel does support Unicode. I tried using [this unicode](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/398/index.htm)(U+0398)for my theta and [this Unicode](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/3b1/index.htm) (U+03B1) for my alpha. The problem is I'm not to sure where this unicode should go in the ui. Qt doesn't say anything about it; so its either overlooked or something I should have already known. I tried to put it in the text field. That didn't work.

This is the latest code I tried:

```
QString alpha;
QString theta;
alpha.setUnicode(U+03B1);
theta.setUnicode(U+0398);
ui->labelExpansionAngle1->setText(alpha);
ui->labelExpansionAngle2->setText(alpha);
ui->labelOrientationAngle->setText(theta);
```

Then I tried:

```
ui->labelExpansionAngle1->setText("\u03B1");
ui->labelExpansionAngle2->setText("\u03B1");
ui->labelOrientationAngle->setText("\u0398");
```

I even tried using some of the other codes from the web pages I posted here. I was hoping that someone could shed some light on how this data needs to be put together. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: "I tried to put it in the text field."  You'll have to include code so we know what you mean by this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try with:

```
theta = QChar(0x98, 0x03);
alpha = QChar(0xb1, 0x03);
```

Comment: That worked great! can I ask where you found this information?

Comment: I was able to solve this by using HTML tagging.

For Theta I used:

<font face="Symbol"><font size="+1">q</font></font><sub>E2</sub>
For Alpha I used:

<font face="Symbol"><font size="+1">q</font></font><sub>E2</sub>

Comment: By reading QChar apidocs and having done similar things before. It's the QChar(uchar cell, uchar row) constructor. HTML of course also works if you need it for a QLabel only, the unicode characters are more generic.

Answer (score 1):

For those using PyQt5, you can directly set the unicode text to a `QLabel` through its [constructor](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.12/qlabel.html#QLabel-1):

```
alpha_label = QLabel('\u03b1')
```

or [setText](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.12/qlabel.html#text-prop):

```
alpha_label.setText('\u03b1')
```

If you need the unicode characters for any other greek letter have a look at:

https://unicode.org/charts/PDF/U0370.pdf

Answer (score 0):

For those using QT on C++

```
QString alpha = QChar(0x03B1);
QString theta = QChar(0x03B8);
```

Use 0x followed by unicode character value. One can find all official unicode characters as mentioned @Pablo Guerrero in the above link